# In a Rails view, how do I display dynamic code within a HTML code snippet?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, erb

Within a Ruby on Rails view, how would I display a HTML code snippet that includes dynamically-generated code?

For example, users see different HTML code snippets depending on their `user.url` (where `url` is stored against a `User` record in the database):

User A may see the following code snippet:

`<a href="www.example-a.com/123">`

User B may see the following code snippet:

`<a href="www.example-b.com/456">`

Comment: how are you generating/saving the custom urls?  That is, how do you know what url to show?

Comment: It'll grab it from the user record in the db, e.g. <%= user.url %>

Comment: If the URL is stored in a usable form, eg "https://user_url.com", could you just show that, exactly as written?   <a href="<%= user.url %>">User url</a>.  Any other code you could share (user model, user.url, other code from your view that isn't working, etc) would be helpful

Comment: I don't think you understand my question - the html link needs to be displayed as a code snippet. What you've suggested would render an actual link - so the user would only see `User url` as a link rather than `<a href="www.example.com">` as a code snippet.

Comment: What about 
`<%=  h "<a href='#{user.url}'>" %>`? 
(h is a method to escape the html characters)

Comment: Also you would enclose the code above in an html <code> tag: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/code

Comment: Thanks, your answer got me part-way there, but I wanted to display the html with double quotes rather than single quotes. Through a bit of experimentation I got it to work using backslashes around the HTML attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be a combination of using `<code>` to display it in a code snippet format, then using the `h` method to initially escape the HTML, and then using backslashes `\` to escape the HTML attributes (the backslashes allow you to use double-quotes inside the HTML instead of just single-quotes). Finally, Ruby interpolation `#{...}` to generate the Ruby code.

```
<code>
  <%= h "<a href=\"#{user.url}\" title=\"My Title\">" %>
</code>
```